# Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource

Tags: java, android, gradle

Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven/androidx/appcompat/appcompat/1.4.0/appcompat-1.4.0.pom'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven/com/google/firebase/firebase-database/20.0.3/firebase-database-20.0.3.pom'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven/androidx/navigation/navigation-fragment/2.3.5/navigation-fragment-2.3.5.pom'.
.....

in the newest Android Studio and Gradle Version

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably caused by JCenter/bintray closing down (https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/). We experience the same. What happens if you change `jcenter` with `mavenCentral` in your .gradle file?

Comment: The same Errors

Comment: Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve androidx.databinding:viewbinding:4.2.2.

Comment: Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven/androidx/databinding/viewbinding/4.2.2/viewbinding-4.2.2.pom'

Comment: Full error:

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.databinding:viewbinding:4.2.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve androidx.databinding:viewbinding:4.2.2.
         > Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven/androidx/databinding/viewbinding/4.2.2/viewbinding-4.2.2.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven/androidx/databinding/viewbinding/4.2.2/viewbinding-4.2.2.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
..........

Comment: It looks like it still looks in jcenter/bintray. Try to look for another place where jcenter is mentioned and replace it with mavenCentral.

Comment: The same problem and nothing helps. I even tried maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }, but it didn't help either.